# php pdo fetch data on specific date return empty result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem to return query based on a specific date that input in variable `$now`

Below is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// bind column to variable
//Connect to DB
$host = "localhost"; //Host Name
$port = '3306'; //Default MySQL Port
$dbname = "mama"; //Database Name
$db_username = "root"; //MySQL Username
$db_password = ""; //MySQL Password

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname"; //Data Source Name = Mysql
$db = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password); //Connect to DB

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
  $now = "2014-01-01";

  //foreach ($query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime <= :now") as $row) {print_r($row);}
  $query->bindParam(':now', $now, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $success = $query->execute();
}
// Catch any exception thrown
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
  // Exit, redirect, whatever you need to do.
}
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<table>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <th>Visit</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
<?php
// Use a foreach over $rows
foreach ($rows as $row) {

    // Using htmlspecialchars() on these as good practice for HTML escaping
    // Since they were fetched via FETCH_OBJ access them as properties with ->
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->log_id) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->dob) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->log_datetime) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->log_count) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->amount) . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like the result to show on the specific date set, but it returns nothing except the table header.

Additional info, my `log_datetime` use DATETIME mysql format.

I did some SO search but non of the question or answer posted in SO can help my question.
Please advise where did I go wrong, I followed the php PDO tutorial but it seems not working.

Comment: You are assuming your queries succeeded. You MUST check for successful `prepare` and `execute`. Given your query has a syntax error, it is impossible for the fetch() code to EVER execute, because there is NO result to fetch FROM. Always assume failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: @Satya no result returned. only show the header. I want the query goes as per the `$now` so the result so return as per the date set.

Comment: Remove that whole `foreach()` since it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @MarcB how do I able to check? by `var_dump($query);` ?

Comment: Check for errors: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php, change the PDO error operation mode: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php (see ATTR_ERRMODE), etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you begin to get your error checking in order, this will start to take shape in a meaningful way for you.

Your query execution is correct, and the SQL statement itself should return the expected values. Your problem still lies in an incorrect transfer of values from the fetched `$row` to their final positions in the `<td>` tags.

Some things to take care of:

- [Set PDO into `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) so it throws exceptions on any error.
- Wrap all the database stuff in `try/catch` to catch any PDO exceptions
- Use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape all the output for HTML
- It is left to you to take some appropriate action in the `catch {}` block

---

```
require('./inc/connection.php');

// Suggest setting PDO into ERRMODE_EXCEPTION so it throws exceptions on any error
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// With PDO in exception mode, wrap all of this in try/catch
try {
  $now = "2014-01-01";

  $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime <= :now");
  $query->bindParam(':now', $now);
  $success = $query->execute();
}
// Catch any exception thrown
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
  // Exit, redirect, whatever you need to do.
}

// Assuming no failure (you didn't exit or redirect)
// You can build your table.

// First fetch all rows:
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

// Now all your rows are in the array. You're done with PDO.
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>DOB</th>
<th>Visit</th>
<th>Qty</th>
<th>Amount</th>
</tr>';

// Use a foreach over $rows
foreach ($rows as $row) {

    // Using htmlspecialchars() on these as good practice for HTML escaping
    // Since they were fetched via FETCH_OBJ access them as properties with ->
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->log_id) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->dob) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->log_datetime) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->log_count) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->amount) . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

// You're done.
```

I removed *all* of the inline `style-` attributes. None of that belongs in your markup and instead should be in the CSS. It can all be handled with a CSS rule like:

```
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

A final note about `$now`: If you really plan to use the current date, there's no need for a bound parameter. You can just call MySQL's `CURDATE()` in the statement directly:

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime <= CURDATE()
```

Comment: thank you so much, just a last question, I input `$now = "2014-01-02'` and it show no result, but if I change it to `2014-01-03` it extract all result which is from `2014-01-02 22:37:27` seems like it automatic add a day? I added `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');` on top of it, but it seems no not working for me.

Comment: Use `WHERE DATE(log_datetime) <= :now` to truncate the datetime to just the date portion. Otherwise, it will only return results up to 2014-01-02 00:00:00 while yours are from later in the day.

Answer (score 1):

You have one small mistake in your SQL syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime <= ?
// ----------------------------------^
```

Comment: This should fix the problem, indeed.

Comment: No, there are additional problems. Like the `fetchAll()` inside a `while` loop condition which will never terminate.

Comment: And the `foreach($query as $row)` which serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the sql syntax, try changing 
    `"SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime = < ?"`
with
    `"SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime <= ?"`

Answer (score -1):

```
while ($query->fetchAll()) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $log_id . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $dob . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $log_datetime . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $log_count . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $amount . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

this will not fetch anything , you need to re-write it like

```
while ($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
 $log_id         = $row->log_id;
    $dob            = $row->dob;
    $log_datetime   = $row->log_datetime;
    $log_count      = $row->log_count;
    $amount         = $row->amount;

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $log_id . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $dob . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $log_datetime . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $log_count . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $amount . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot use `fetchAll()` inside a `while` loop.  Store the result first, then `foreach` over it.  Using `fetchAll()` as a loop condition will never terminate.

Comment: @satya no result return as well

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski do you mind to show some example, based on your explanation, I try to twist around but no luck to get it right.

Comment: @Nescafe What is currently above `while ($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))` will work correctly as long as the query itself was executed.  Did you put in error checking as suggested earlier? Did you remove that other earlier `foreach ($query as $row)` loop?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i did a check for `$row` and the error --> `PDO::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )` also, I updated my current code in first post

Comment: @Nescafe see my answer. You're sort of on the right track but could benefit from deeper explanation at this point.